# How to create Wordpress search bar in PHP?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, search

I am using Wordpress (and Bootstrap) and I would like to create my own Search bar in PHP, that I could custom. It should be displayed only in one specific page, and should be able to search posted articles.
I am beginner in php and I already spent hours trying to figured it out by my own research, but I couldn't get a good working result.
For the ones who know how to resolve my issue, I will very much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search bar in wordpress can be created with this single piece of code.

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

Need to customize it?

Create a file called searchform.php and insert this piece of code.

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?></span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search …', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) ?>" />
</form>
```

You can customize the above code so that it fits you need.

Create a new file called as search.php to output the search result.

Reference :-

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/

Edit:-

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php
                    /* translators: %s: search query. */
                    printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'materialpress' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' );
                ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                /* Make sure the template is your content.php */
                get_template_part('content');

            endwhile;

            the_posts_navigation();

        else :
            /* Show no content found page */
            echo 'Not posts found';

        endif; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); get_footer();
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Hi Rajendran, thank you for you answer! Now, when I search it leads me to a blank page. How could I make the posts appear as result of the search?

Comment: My search.php file is empty… is there maybe something I have to put in it to output the search result?

Comment: Search.php should hav the wp loop to populate the search query. I will update my answer with a simple search.php code.

Comment: Hi Rajendran, the search leads to an error now :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /www/htdocs/w00f75e8/do-not-remove-this-folder/wp-content/themes/Temporary-Gallery/search.php on line 26

When I remove the ';' on line 26, a second error happens then :

Fatal error: Call to undefined function twentyseventeen_get_svg() in /www/htdocs/w00f75e8/do-not-remove-this-folder/wp-content/themes/Temporary-Gallery/search.php on line 22

I use my own theme, which is called Temporary Gallery. I replaced on line 22 by temporarygallery_get_svg but it is still error…

Comment: Added the new code along with the comments to understand what you need to change.

Comment: Ok thanks! no errors anymore! Now and after the search, it is showing Lorem Ipsum text, full with container.

Comment: Glad that it worked mark this as solved.

Comment: But I dont understand why there is a Lorem Ipsum text when I search for posts. Why is it not showing the post I am searching for?

Comment: Put the screenshot of your search result so that I can tell what is wrong.

Comment: I posted an answer with the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

[AJAX Live Search](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp)

```js
function showResult(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
<div id="livesearch"></div>
</form>
```

Source code explanation:

If the input field is empty (str.length==0), the function clears the content of the livesearch placeholder and exits the function.

If the input field is not empty, the showResult() function executes the following:

- Create an XMLHttpRequest object
- Create the function to be executed when the server response is ready
- Send the request off to a file on the server
- Notice that a parameter (q) is added to the URL (with the content of
  the input field)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the screen shot of :
 1. the search bar
 2. the search result
3. I searched for something else, and here comes the same lorem ipsum text and the design moved.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Search something like foo. You shoud get no posts found. I also updated my code check my answer.

Comment: @RajendranNadar Whatever I am searching for, it leads to this result (see screenshot). It says: "You have searched the archives of the Temporary Gallery site with the query "foo". If the results do not suit you, you can try one of these links…" + lorem ipsum is there and the sidebar.

Comment: Yup that is what a search bar does. The output is correct. The search page is showing the lorem ipsum post that you made check all the post in backend.

Comment: But if I search for one or another things, which are different title/permalink/content, it always shows up the same lorem ipsum. I would like to search for something and get a search output with only what I searched for. I would rather avoid a 'search by yourself in those links' manner of searching. If I have a post called "My first post ever", and if my searching is "first post", is it possible to get the "My first post ever" post's title as the only suggestion result?

Comment: The keyword used to search will be first userd to check if any post title consists of that keyword then it will check in content of the post. All the posts &amp; pages related to the keyword will be displayed.

Comment: Ok, I understand! Is there anyway I can show only the post titles and nothing else?

Comment: Great! Do have any idea how it can be achieved? (Thank you again for your help, as you can see, I am beginner…)

Comment: Yes you can do that. If you don't know how to do that start a new question bcuz it is out of scope of this question. Paste link here I will be happy to help you. Don't forget to tag as solved.

Comment: @RajendranNadar Ok! Thank you so much. Here is the link of the new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897277/wordpress-search-bar-outputting-only-posts-titles

Answer (score 0):

Rajendran, here is the screenshot of the latest uptade.

[image]